# Draw to canvas using javascript within a table

Tags: javascript, canvas

I grabbed this code from another thread.  Works great until I put it into a table.  The drawing is off vertically.  I've tried everything I can think of.

```js
var canvas, ctx, flag = false,
    prevX = 0,
    currX = 0,
    prevY = 0,
    currY = 0,
    dot_flag = false;

window.onload = function () {
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    w = canvas.width;
    h = canvas.height;

    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
        findxy('move', e)
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
        findxy('down', e)
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
        findxy('up', e)
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
        findxy('out', e)
    }, false);
}

function draw() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
    ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function findxy(res, e) {
    if (res == 'down') {
        prevX = currX;
        prevY = currY;
        currX = e.clientX; - canvas.offsetLeft;
        currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;

        flag = true;
        dot_flag = true;
        if (dot_flag) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = "black";
            ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
            ctx.closePath();
            dot_flag = false;
        }
    }
    if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
        flag = false;
    }
    if (res == 'move') {
        if (flag) {
            prevX = currX;
            prevY = currY;
            currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
            draw();
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr height=100>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style='border:1px solid black;'>
            <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If you remove the table, it works as it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the offsets from

```
canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
```

Using canvas.offsetTop and canvas.offsetLeft gives you offsets relative to the parent.

```js
var canvas, ctx, flag = false,
    prevX = 0,
    currX = 0,
    prevY = 0,
    currY = 0,
    dot_flag = false;

window.onload = function () {
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    w = canvas.width;
    h = canvas.height;

    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
        findxy('move', e)
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
        findxy('down', e)
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
        findxy('up', e)
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
        findxy('out', e)
    }, false);
}

function draw() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
    ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function findxy(res, e) {
    if (res == 'down') {
        prevX = currX;
        prevY = currY;
        rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        currX = e.clientX - rect.left;
        currY = e.clientY - rect.top;

        flag = true;
        dot_flag = true;
        if (dot_flag) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = "black";
            ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
            ctx.closePath();
            dot_flag = false;
        }
    }
    if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
        flag = false;
    }
    if (res == 'move') {
        if (flag) {
            prevX = currX;
            prevY = currY;
            currX = e.clientX - rect.left;
            currY = e.clientY - rect.top;
            draw();
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr height=100>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style='border:1px solid black;'>
            <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```